# SQL Converting a text field to other text

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a text field in a table that is populated by a trigger. This information is then processed and posted into a program, however the text is not valid for the program and needs to be converted into a valid text value.

Example:
The value inputted into the field can either be 'Sterling' or 'EUROS' but this needs to be converted into 'GBP' (if the value is 'Sterling') or 'EUR' (if the value is 'EUROS') before it attempts to post to program.

How do I do this?

Comment: Is John your pen name? What programming language you are using? If possible show the code.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using. The `CASE` statement is what you're looking for

Comment: I'm using SQL 2008, I dont really have any code at the moment.

Comment: I realise that I need to use an if/else statement to differentiate between the two possible values but it's just how to convert the two values into valid text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check the following

```
Select case <fieldname> when  'Sterling'  then 'GBP' when 'EUROS' then 'EUR' end
from <tableName>
```